# Cannot get rid of warning C4554

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++, visual-studio-2015

This code always produces a C4554 warning when compiling in [Visual Studio 2015](http://webcompiler.cloudapp.net/). However, g++ (on Coliru) compiles it without warnings. The warning message is:

> warning C4554: '<<': check operator precedence for possible error; use parentheses to clarify precedence

According to [this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence), operator- takes precedence over operator<<. So the parentheses shouldn't be even required. (Omitting them gives the same warning.) Can someone tell me reason for this warning, or how to get rid of it?

```
#include <array>

template<int C>
void F(std::array<int, 2 << (C-1)> const&) // 2 << (2-1) = 4
{
}

int main()
{
    std::array<int,4> arr;
    F<2>(arr);
}
```

Comment: Why are you placing a statement expression in a parameter declaration? I'm pretty sure there's more wrong than just that warning.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ : The question is, how do you satisfy the compiler sufficiently to silence the warning? Usefulness of the code is a moot point.

Comment: Shouldn't be necessary, but does `template<int C> void F(std::array<int, (2 << (C-1))> const&)` work?

Comment: No combination of parentheses silence the warning, and I can't get it to go away by placing `#pragma warning(suppress: 4554)` on the line above, either. These things happen when you write obfuscated code... The warning is just trying to be helpful, it isn't prepared for a programmer as clever as you.

Comment: How bout wrapping the calculation in a TMP wrappsr struct, so that the expression isn't directly in the declaration!?

Comment: @Cody Gray: Well, it's a SSCCE. I would not consider the actual function to be obfuscated code. I have discovered a hackish workaround which is not exactly equivalent, but silences the warning. Just move the compile-time expression like this: `template<int C, int K = 2 << (C-1)>
void F(std::array<int, K> const&)`. I guess, I should file a VC++ bug report, although it doesn't seem like the sort of thing that will get much attention.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may try this:

```
constexpr std::size_t calc_size(int param)
{
    return 2 << (param - 1);
}

template<int C>
void F(std::array<int, calc_size(C)> const&) // 2 << (2-1) = 4
{
}
```

Comment: Perfect. For earlier C++ versions, I guess the approach of @Martin Ba can be used: `template<int X>
struct CalcSize
{
    static const int Y = 2 << (X-1);
};

template<int C>
void F(std::array<int, CalcSize<C>::Y > const&){} `

Answer (score -1):

In Visual Studio 2015, use `#pragma warning( disable : C4554 )` to disable  the specified warning message. However, It is not wise to disable warning messages though.

More documentation here...
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa273936(v=vs.60).aspx

See this link to see why the warning `C4554` appears...
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5d2e57c5.aspx

Comment: **(1)** This pragma works for *all* versions of Visual Studio, not just VS 2015, so that qualifier is unnecessary. **(2)** When using it, you do *not* include the `C` prefix, just the number. **(3)** This *globally* disables the error, which is almost certainly a bad idea. If you wanted to do that, you'd just disable it on the command line, rather than with a random line of code buried in some source file. If you're going to do this, the only minimally sane approach would involve a combination of `#pragma warning(push)` and `#pragma warning(pop)`